# How to add a content in a file in linux without opening the file using vi or cat command

Tags: linux

I want to add a content in a file in linux without opening that file using vi or cat command

Lets say I have a file as abc.txt file and the content of the file is 
"a quick fox jumps over the lazy dog" and now I want to add the word "brown" between the words "quick" and "fox" so that it should be "a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog". But i want to add this word without opening the file using vi or cat.

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Comment: `sed -i 's/quick/quick brown/g' abc.txt`, if you know exactly what contents of the file is.

Comment: `echo "a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" > /path_to_your_file/abc.txt`(which infact replaces your file)

Comment: @evilive  thanks for the response but i cant replace the file as it has other contents in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple find and replace activity which you can do with `sed` command as follows,

```
sed -i 's/quick/quick brown/g' abc.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

You'd do it using Emacs, of course.

Comment: Is this answer written to generate humor? I couldn't get it! Not using `vi` OR `cat`,but using `emacs`!!!